# Movie about apocalypse in dreams that become reality

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched this movie in around 2000s. I really didn't remember details about this movie except some scenes and its language is English.

Scene I.

> There is a group of people (with one of them being the main character)
> who are going to a certain place when suddenly they are warned by a
> stranger that the "end times" are near
>
> Then the stranger also gives them spoilers about the signs of the end
> times, but they initially don't believe it until they start to realize
> that something is not right around them. The signs of the end times
> mentioned by the stranger begin to appear.
>
> One of the signs of the end times in the movie that left a strong
> impression on me is when drinking water, tap water, and even the ocean
> turns red.

Scene II - Probably Ending

> So, when the end times have arrived, the next scene immediately
> transitions to the main character's bedroom, and well... they wake up
> and realize that it was all just a dream.
>
> The main character finally wakes up in the real world and goes to the
> bathroom to wash their face... and here's where I start feeling uneasy
> when I hear the sound of the water being 'slightly different' as it
> flows from the sink. My gut feeling tells me that when they wash their
> face, the water will actually turn red, just like in their dream.

**Note**:

This is not [**The Reaping**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Reaping) as far as I can remember.

Comment: Do you recall if the main character was male or female?

Comment: @LogicDictates I think it's male and I am maybe wrong but he kind look like Leonardo DiCaprio